# TypeError: Profile is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
const {
  Profile
} = require('../models')

module.exports.post = async(req, res) => {
  const file = req.file;
  try {
    const profile = new Profile({
      file: file,
      fullname: req.body.fullname,
      brandname: req.body.brandname,
      skill1: req.body.skill1,
      skill2: req.body.skill2,
      skill3: req.body.skill3,
      skill4: req.body.skill4,
      socail_handle1: req.body.socail_handle1,
      socail_handle2: req.body.socail_handle2
    })
    const result = await profile.save()
    console.log(result)
    return res.status(201).json({
      message: "Done upload!"
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return res.status(500).send({
      error: 'An Error has occured trying to upload'
    });
  }
},
```

**Module/Profile.js File**

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

function hashPassword(profile) {
    const SALT_FACTOR = 8

    if (!profile.changed('password')) {
        return;
    }
    return bcrypt
        .genSalt(SALT_FACTOR)
        .then(salt => bcrypt.hashSync(profile.password, salt, null))
        .then(hash => {
            profile.setDataValue('password', hash)
        })
}
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Profile = sequelize.define('hemtec_profile', {
         file: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING
         },
         fullname: {
           type: DataTypes.STRING
         },
         brandname: DataTypes.STRING,
         email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true
        },
         password: DataTypes.STRING,
         skill1: DataTypes.STRING,
         skill2: DataTypes.STRING,
         skill3: DataTypes.STRING,
         skill4: DataTypes.STRING,
         socail_handle1: DataTypes.STRING,
         socail_handle2: DataTypes.STRING,
     }, {
      hooks: {
          beforeSave: hashPassword
      }
    })
    Profile.prototype.comparePassword = function (password) {
      return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password)
  }
     return Profile
}
```

This is my module/profile

This is my code which am been trying run but telling the Profile is not a constructor.

The shocking part was this code was running perfectly, until I made some changes then it started bringing that error. And I undo the changes made but still doesn't stop bringing the error.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: What's in `../models`? How does it define `Profile`?

Comment: Can you post the definition of `Profile`? It's hard to understand the situation otherwise.

Comment: I have had the file